# Vertical Align List (CSS)

Tags: css, list, vertical-alignment

I was wondering on what should I do to make the list align vertically to the image, as shown below:

[image]

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the HTML + CSS if anyone's interested:

```
<header>
<img src="URL" />
<ul>
<li>ListItem 01</li>
<li>ListItem 02</li>
<li>ListItem 03</li>
</ul>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
li {display: inline;}
```

Comment: I guess you mean "align horizontally"...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions to achieve what you ask. This is just one possible solution, add this to your css:

```
header>img, header>ul>li {
  float: left
}
```

Take a look to [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bHzAr/), there are some more styles than the ones provided above, but I hope it will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just format it as a table. But is your preference handling it with CSS?
Also, this is a good resource for things like this: http://www.unheap.com/media/images/bttrlazyloading/

Comment: It's supposed to be a header, here's the HTML code: <header><img src="URL" /><ul><li>Item 01</li>...</ul></header> Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You only need apply the next css to your li of ul

```
li
{
display:inline;
}
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) for more information.